# Android studio - error: unknown element <meta-notification> found

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm getting a error from android studio when building, this seems to be somewhere misplaced something in my manifest file. i tried searching for a solution and nothing seems to be working for me, i'm new to this and was following a tutorial. can someone please look into my manifest file and see what i have done wrong?

Also i see so many places red in my code and when i move the mouse the error is "Attribute is not allowed here", please can someone help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.www.riderapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="28" />

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <!-- Include required permissions for Google Maps API to run. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" /> <!-- Required by older versions of Google Play services to create IID tokens -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="com.example.www.riderapp.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-notification
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.www.riderapp.Welcome"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.www.riderapp.Home"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.example.www.riderapp.Service.MyFirebaseIdService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.example.www.riderapp.Service.MyFirebaseMessaging" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="26.1.0" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:permission="com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.permission.LAUNCH_FEDERATED_SIGN_IN"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar"
            android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
    </service>
    <!--
         FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime,
         no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
    -->
    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementJobService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!--
         FirebaseInstanceIdService performs security checks at runtime,
         no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
    -->
    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.www.riderapp.firebaseinitprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:initOrder="100" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: in which line is displaying the error?

Answer (score 0):

how do you have 2 launcher :D

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

remove one of them and leave the start point